# Internacionalización en PHP con Xampp

Tags: php, apache

Estoy creando una aplicación web con `Xampp` y me gustaría internacionalizarla. Ya creé los archivos `.po` con `gettext` y añadí a los ficheros de `PHP` las indicaciones para que el usuario una vez que seleccione el idioma le aparezca traducido.

Realizo todo esto y no me lo traduce a no ser que sea en Español.

¿Habría alguna manera o tiene que ver la configuración de `Apache` o `PHP`?. Si es así os agradecería que me intentaseis solucionar la duda.

**Intento solucionar el problema** de que me escoja el idioma por la localización.
No se si me explico bien pero el problema que tengo también aparece en este hilo, el cual no se solucionó: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/gettext-not-working-under-local-xampp/54975
Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si se hacen los archivos de traducción definiendo variables con los nombres entones va.

Answer (score 1):

mira si lo que explican en está página

[internacionalización web con php](http://blackshell.usebox.net/archive/internacionalizacion-web-facil-con-php.html)

es lo que necesitas

Answer (score 0):

Del sitio inglés [How to run or load .po/.mo files for localization in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802093/how-to-run-or-load-po-mo-files-for-localization-in-php)

Los dos tipos de archivos que tengas .po y .mo generados con gettext gnu
los debes guardar en

```
pathroot/locale/en_EN/LC_MESSAGES/nombrerecurso.mo
```

Primero debes definir que idioma quieres usar en PHP

```
putenv("LANG=da_DK"); 
setlocale('LC_ALL', "da_DK"); 
bindtextdomain("mycatalog", "./locale/");  
textdomain("mycatalog");
```

Para mostrar el recurso

```
echo _("Hello world");   // Para mostrar Hola mundo
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar. Lo que indicas ya lo tengo hecho. El problema es que solo me traduce cuando es Español y no en el resto de idiomas. Es como si cogiese la localización por defecto o algo así el xampp

Comment: @adamista si el final lo tienes que subir en un servidor a internet, compruebalo antes de buscar una solución apra xamp, que puede que funcione bien en otros servidores ya precofigurados.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, en otros servidores si funciona el problema es que me obligan a utilizar XAMPP

Comment: @adamista mira por este hilo a ver si encuentras la solución https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/gettext-not-working-under-local-xampp/54975 o bien mirar si la nueva versión de xamp que la han mejorado funciona.

Comment: Hola gracias de nuevo, el hilo que me mandaste para seguir es exactamente lo que me ocurre, pero no está solucionado el problema. En cuanto a la versión de xampp tengo la más nueva

Comment: He estado mirando y creo que descomentando la linea de xampp en la que aparece la librería curl me permite internacionalizar sin embargo tampoco funciona.

Comment: No, tampoco funciona. Igual si hago a mano los archivos de traducción va.

Comment: Me alegro que hayas encontrado la solución, puedes publicar la autosolución